# jquery-autocomplete plugin search

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

There is this [jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete) plugin 
which allows you to search for the exact string only..

So lets say this is the data..

```
   [
        ['apple is good'],
        ['apple grows on tree'],
        ['the tree and the apple'],
        ['red apple'],
        ['apple tree']
    ]
```

Now searching for "apple" should show all.

But when typing "apple tree"  it only returns back "apple tree". 
I want it to return the smart results (2,3 and 5).

- "apple grows on tree"
- "the tree and the apple"
- "apple tree"

This means: it should re-evaluate the search again for each word (but filter it from the already filtered results)

This plugin allows you to provide your own search..

what can the refined search which will enable us to smartly search look like?

It needs to ignore whitespace and split the search query in to words to evaluate each word one after the other...

```
$("#textInputEle").autocomplete({
    url:"path/to/data.json",
    filter: function(result, filter) {
     //whats should this function be?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `filter` option to supply your own filtering logic.

The function you supply takes `result` and `filter` parameters. The `filter` parameter is what the user has searched for. The `result` parameter is an item in the list of suggestions. Your function must return `true` (if the suggestion is a match), or `false` (if the suggestion is not a match).

The logic to do what you're trying to accomplish could look something like this:

1. Split the `result` you're passed by space (`" "`) into an array of terms.
2. Create a regular expression out of each string in the array of terms
3. Ensure what the user typed matches each regular expression

That would look something like this:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    data: [
        ['apple is good'],
        ['apple grows on tree'],
        ['the tree and the apple'],
        ['red apple'],
        ['apple tree']
        ],
    filter: function(result, filter) {
        var terms = filter.split(" "),
            match = true,
            i = 0,
            regex;

        for (; match && i < terms.length; i++) {
            regex = new RegExp(terms[i]);
            match = match && regex.test(result.value);
        }

        return match;
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ztkX2/1/

Comment: Simplified the example--I was iterating twice and didn't mean to.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the out-of-box functionality of jquery autocomplete will only return results that contain the phrase "apple tree".  So, it would return #5 from your example, but it would also return true for phrases such as "He lives near an apple tree" and "The apple tree is the largest in her yard."