# Update a JQuery autocomplete issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Searching through Stack Overflow, I found the exact question I needed already answered.  The only problem was it was answered for a depriciated JQuery Autocomplete widget.  That topic is here: [jquery-autocomplete plugin search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042172/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-search)

In essence what I need to do witih JQuery Autocomplete is to find all of the search terms in the database and find them in any order.  For example if we had a database that looked like:

```
var availableTags = [  
  "apple is good",  
  "apple grows on tree",  
  "the tree and the apple",  
  "red apple",  
  "apple tree"  
];
```

And we searched for "apple tree", we would get this:

"apple grows on tree",
"the tree and the apple",
"apple tree",

I hope that is clear enough!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: as per your search for apple tree the result will be apple tree only. if you want result what you have mentioned, then its better to write won autocomplete search box.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is to use JQueryUI autocomplete feature: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

It is easy to use and quite powerful. I guess it can handle what you need.

Otherwise, you can create your own autocomplete feature by yourselves. For that, just use simple regex: for each input word, test if word is found in source data. If you have only one match, append data to your outcome.

Here is a sample of JS code using RegExp:

```
// Here your tags
var availableTags = [
    "apple is good",
    "amazing apple"
    // ...
];

// The main function
// $target is the input field
function autocomplete($target) {
    var outcome;
    var words;
    var input;
    var tmp;

    outcome = new Array(); // wraps tags which match autcompletion
    words = new Array(); // wraps all words from your input
    input = $target.val().trim(); // input value

    if (input === '') {
        // No words, do nothing
        return outcome;
    }

    // First step: browse input to extract all
    // words
    tmp = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var current = input[i];

        if (current === ' ') {
            words.push(tmp);
            tmp = '';
        } else {
            tmp += current;
        }
    }

    // Do no forget pending word
    words.push(tmp);

    // Second step: browse each checked-in tag
    // and test if all provided words are found
    // in it
    for (var i = 0; i < availableTags.length; i++) {
        var isCancelled = false;
        var j = 0;
        var current = availableTags[i];

        while (j < words.length && !isCancelled) {
            var r = new RegExp(words[j], 'gi');

            if (r.test(current)) {
                // Ok word was found, go ahead
                j++;
            } else {
                // Word was not here. You do not
                // need to go ahead because you
                // want to find all words in
                // your tag
                isCancelled = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isCancelled) {
            // If operation was not cancelled,
            // save tag
            outcome.push(current);
        }
    }

    return outcome;
}
```

Comment: I am already using jquery autocomplete, as I stated in the question.  Can you help me get this working with it?  I know it is powerful, and I'm trying to read the online manual for it.  Where should I start?